# option value not populated in angular js from the get object of spring controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Simple requirement to populate the array object in the angular js option, the array object is populated from the spring controller.

The angular js has http get request, it seems the problem is that with the http get request, the reason, i had added test items option, when i include the http get the items option is not populated.

below is the code of my simple requirement.

**view.jsp**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "Gopala";
    $scope.lastName= "Krishnan";
    $scope.items = [{name: 'one', age: 30 },{ name: 'two', age: 27 },{ name: 'three', age: 50 }];

    $http.get('http://169.52.203.189:8080/LDODashBoard/AppView?appid=CV-APAC-CHECKOUT').success(function(data) {
        $scope.appview = data;
    });
});
</script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/LDODashBoard/css/mystyle.css" /> 
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <p>selected item is : {{firstName}}</p>
  <p>selected item is : {{lastName}}</p>
   <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items">
   </select>
   <select ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-options="appview1.oDATE for appview1 in appview">
   </select>

</div>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AppViewJson",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public ModelAndView monitorUnixProcessJson(
    @RequestParam(value = "appid", required = false) String appviewid,
     Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {

        log.info("inisde AppViewJson json method");
        List <AppViewBatchDetails> appviewbatchlist = null;

           try {

               if (!appviewid.isEmpty())    {

                   WebPageURLReader webpagereader = new WebPageURLReader();
                   webpagereader.extractNeededAppview(appviewid);
                   webpagereader.executeRetrieveAppviewDetailsWrapper();
                   appviewbatchlist = webpagereader.returnMatchedAppviewJobs();

               }
                //return the dummy outputdisplay page, show nothing
                return (new ModelAndView("AppviewDisplayJsonPage","appviewbatch",appviewbatchlist));
           }
           catch (Exception e){
               log.error("exception received here!!!!");
           }

          return (new ModelAndView(CommonConstants.OutputDisplayPage,"",""));
    }
}
```

Comment: The comment in your controller says _"show nothing"_. So what does the controller return?

Comment: it is incorrect comment, i suspect from angular js the http get call is not getting any idea or inputs..